# Unable to check a nested object property by using the ".nested" flag and bracket notation

Tags: javascript, chai

Chai 4 and later's `.nested.property()` was `.deep.property()` in earlier versions. The issue I'm describing is present both with `.nested.property()` in Chai 4 or later and with `.deep.property()` in versions prior to 4.

I've been trying to use the `.nested` flag and bracket notation to check for the value of a nested property. When I try to address into arrays, it works, but if I want to address into an object by doing `"a['name']"`, it does not work. This is confusing because in JavaScript `a.name` and `a["name"]` would both refer to the same property, and in some cases we have to use the brackets due to the structure of the name.

I have an example of the issue below. If you run this, you'll see `"first expect passed"`, but you won't see `"second expect passed"` because the second assertion fails.

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

const obj = {
    "a": ["foo", "bar"],
    "b": { "foo-bar": 1},
};

expect(obj).to.have.nested.property("a[1]").equal("bar");
console.log("first expect passed");


expect(obj).to.have.nested.property("b['foo-bar']").equal(1);
console.log("second expect passed");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not clearly documented but the issue is that Chai is not actually interpreting the argument you pass to `.property` in the *exact* same way a JavaScript interpreter would. It is natural to go with `b['foo-bar']` because that's what you'd expect you'd **have** to do if you were accessing the property in JavaScript code, but this won't work with Chai. What you have to do is:

```
expect(obj).to.have.nested.property("b.foo-bar").equal(1);
console.log("second expect passed");
```

The bracket notation in `.property` is essentially only for addressing into arrays. When it comes to objects you have to use the dot notation, even in cases where it would be invalid JavaScript.